# how to compare value of variable with value of all elements in vector?

Tags: c++, vector, lower-bound

```
vector<int> v;
int n, in;
cin >> n;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> in;
    v.push_back(in);
}
sort(v.begin(), v.end());
int y;
cin >> y;
vector<int>::iterator low;
low = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), y);
if (y == in) {
    cout << "Yes" << " " << (low - v.begin() + 1) << "\n";
}
else {
    cout << "No" << " " << (low - v.begin() + 1) << "\n";
}
```

If I enter `y=16`, but none of the elements in vector have a value of `16`, it should output the statement inside `else`. But it outputs the statement inside `if` instead.

Does anyone know how to fix my problem?

Comment: What is `in` in you example ? please add a working example so we can try

Comment: I cannot help, you haven't included what `in` is as used in `if (y == in)`.

Comment: Also, I don't understand the end goal... is it to check if an element of `v` equals `y`?

Comment: [how to compare value of each elements in vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75907342/how-to-compare-value-of-each-elements-in-vector)

Comment: Was `if (y == in)` supposed to be `if (y == *low)`?

Comment: @Parsa That would cause Undefined Behavior if `y` is not found in the `vector`, since `low` will be the `end` iterator, which cannot be dereferenced.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sure, it would be UB, but would clarify the the OP's intention

Answer (score 2):

In the statement `if (y == in)`, `in` is the last input value that was pushed into the `vector`.  So, you are simply comparing if the value of `y` is equal to the previous input value that preceded it, without any regard to the contents of the `vector` at all.

If your goal is to check whether the value of `y` *exists* in the `vector`, you should be using [`std::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) instead of [`std::lower_bound()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) (and, you won't need the `std::sort()` anymore, either), eg:

```
vector<int>::iterator iter;
iter = find(v.begin(), v.end(), y);
if (iter != v.end()) {
    cout << "Yes" << " " << distance(v.begin(), iter) + 1 << "\n";
}
else {
    cout << "No" << "\n";
}
```

Comment: C++23 would introduce [`std::ranges::contains(v, y)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/contains)